# Use all arguments to a bash function in constructing a URL

Tags: bash

Say I have a Bash function **so** like this

```
function so
{
    open https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=$1
}
```

Which i invoke from a shell like this

```
jessescott@Jesses-MacBook-Pro:~$ so foo
```

which gives me https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foo

Now if i want to search for

```
jessescott@Jesses-MacBook-Pro:~$ so foo bar
```

this won't capture 'bar' because the arguments are split by the whitespace.

I can of course add `$2` to the function, but i want `n`-args to be able to be passed.

I can also escape the `$1` like this

```
function so
{
    open https://stackoverflow.com/search?q="$1"
}
```

which requires me to go

```
jessescott@Jesses-MacBook-Pro:~$ so 'foo bar'
```

... this works, but is not optimum b/c of having to remember to escape my quotes.

Am I missing an obvious other solution in my function?

Comment: Umm, that's a **function**, not an alias. Two completely different things.

Comment: That's a function, not an alias (which is fine; aliases suck for many reasons, including but not limited to being unable to do what you are attempting here).

Comment: Yeah sorry, it is a function, updated title

Comment: Sounds to me like you want `so() { open https://stackoverflow.com/search?q="$*"; }` -- concatenating all the arguments together into a single string. That said, quoting is **much** safer/better; you're going to get a lot of undesired/unwanted side effects from unquoted expansion.

Comment: BTW, re: the syntax above *not* using the `function` keyword, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Let's say you run `so why does *.txt not include .foo.txt` -- the `*.txt` will be changed to a list of text files in your current directory unless you make it `so "why does *.txt not include foo.txt"` before the `so` function is even called, so there's nothing you can do inside the function to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your goal is to concatenate all arguments together into a single string to pass as a URL, `"$*"` is the tool for the job:

```
so() { open https://stackoverflow.com/search?q="$*"; }
```

This uses the first letter in `IFS` (by default, a space) to separate all the arguments.

---

That said, this isn't generally safe when your questions can contain arbitrary text. Consider accepting input on stdin instead; for example:

```
so() {
  local title
  IFS= read -r -p 'Question title: ' title
  [[ $title ]] && open https://stackoverflow.com/search?q="$title"
}
```

...which, by reading input in a context where it can't possibly be parsed as a shell command, is safe even for questions like, say, `How can I safely pass the value assigned with var=$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\'' on a SSH command line?`

Comment: thx Charles, this does what I want.
idk that i'm too concerned about quoting side effects as this is simply a scoped search function for utility, but can you elaborate on "That said, quoting is much safer/better; you're going to get a lot of undesired/unwanted side effects from unquoted expansion" ?

Comment: [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) is a good place to start, or [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086) (the warning you'll get when pasting your code into http://shellcheck.net/).

Comment: ...then again, I also gave you a very specific example of where not quoting will throw you off in [my most recent comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190399/bash-allow-varargs-to-bash-function#comment99005996_56190399).

Comment: @jesses.co.tt, ...btw, as a rule, I strongly suggest making an effort to get in good habits even when you think it doesn't matter. The worst data-loss event I've been present for was when someone thought quotes didn't matter because all the files in a directory were supposed to comply with a strict specification; a bug in a separate program dumped random memory into a filename, a name with a whitespace-surrounded `*` existed, and in trying to delete that file, months of backups of logs used to support customer billing were deleted.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt, ...If you get in the habit of doing it right even when it doesn't matter, you won't have expensive surprises when it unexpectedly does.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Not following best practices when coding is like not wearing a seat belt when driving until you expect to have an accident - YMMV :-).

Comment: I've been developing for 10 years, i know how to follow best practices.
But I am not a bash expert, and am admittedly out of my domain expertise here.
I am just going off of your lead, so confused why you are putting forth an answer that isn't secure or stable... ??

Comment: The *answer* is secure and stable. The *usage mode* it's intended to support is not. That is to say, it's not the `so` function itself but expansions made by the calling shell when you invoke it with an arbitrary set of unquoted or inadequately-quoted arguments that are likely source of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **$@** which is an array of all the input parameters.

In you example, it will be something like:

```
    open https://stackoverflow.com/search?q="$@"
```

Comment: That's good to know! I am still finding that I need to escape the characters in bash though - `so 'foo bar'`...

Comment: @jesses.co.tt, right, as it is right now, only the first argument will be concatenated to the URL, and future ones will be passed to `open` separately.

Comment: ...so, with the code in this answer, `so hello world` will run `open 'https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hello' world`, not `open 'https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hello world'`.